# How to find the shape parameters of a beta density that matches two quantiles in Python?

Tags: python, r, numpy, scipy, distribution

In R there is the **[beta.select()](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/LearnBayes/versions/2.15.1/topics/beta.select)** function, which *finds the shape parameters of a beta density that matches the knowledge of two quantiles of the distribution*.

Here is an example from [the documentation](https://www.rdocumentation.org/packages/LearnBayes/versions/2.15.1/topics/beta.select):

```
quantile1=list(p=.5,x=0.25)
quantile2=list(p=.9,x=0.45)
beta.select(quantile1,quantile2)
```

However, to do the same in Python, I haven't found any similar method in the [beta documentation of scipy](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.stats.beta.html).

- Is there any alternative to the scipy library to perform this task?
- What is the equivalent of the R's quantile generation with `list()` in Python? I know how to compute the quantile of a given array with [np.quantile()](https://www.geeksforgeeks.org/numpy-quantile-in-python/), but it expect an array as input, not the probability (e.g `p=.5`).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no equivalent function in SciPy.  Here's an implementation based on [`scipy.special.betainc`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.special.betainc.html) and [`scipy.optimize.fsolve`](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.optimize.fsolve.html):

```
from scipy.special import betainc
from scipy.optimize import fsolve


def _beta_select_equation(params, p1, x1, p2, x2):
    return betainc(*params, [x1, x2]) - [p1, p2]


def beta_select(p1, x1, p2, x2):
    params, info, status, mesg = fsolve(_beta_select_equation, [1, 1],
                                        args=(p1, x1, p2, x2), xtol=1e-12,
                                        full_output=True)
    if status != 1:
        raise RuntimeError(f'fsolve failed: {mesg}')
    return params
```

For example,

```
In [21]: beta_select(p1=0.5, x1=0.25, p2=0.9, x2=0.45)
Out[21]: array([2.66897386, 7.36479059])
```